# haskell のメモリリークはどうやったらデバッグできる？

Tags: haskell

[なぜこのコードはスペースリークしますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36399/754) を見ていて、次の疑問が生じました。

- Haskell におけるメモリリークはどうやったらデバッグできるのか

というのも、上記のケースでは、プログラムの構造がシンプルであったため、目確認でも問題の箇所を特定することができますが、プログラム構造が複雑になった時には、実質これは不可能になると考えられます。

### 質問

haskell のコードでメモリリークをデバッグするには、どのような方法がありますか？

Answer (score 3):

GHCのヒーププロファイリング機能を使いましょう。
下記のリンクを参考にどうぞ。

- http://itpro.nikkeibp.co.jp/article/COLUMN/20110308/358081/
- http://www.kotha.net/ghcguide_ja/latest/profiling.html
- https://medium.com/@maoe/ghc%E3%83%92%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AE%E6%89%8B%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D-md-bb8d180230f6

なお、stackを利用している場合は、 `stack build --profile` と、 `--profile` オプションを使用すると楽ちんです。